# Certain Windows users cant see certain table in Oracle using SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

We do not have admin access to Oracle DB, our sales system provider runs it.

On our BI server if I login to windows as myself and I install the SQL Developer and use the report account to access the sales db I can see the Product Table and other tables.

If I login as ADMINISTRATOR on the BI server and use the report account to access the sales db I cannot see the Product Table but can see other tables.

If a colleague logs in on the BI Server and install the SQL developer and use the report account to access the sales db he cannot see the Product Table but can see other tables.

If we create a new user based of my windows user, logon to the BI Server and use the report account to access the sales db and install the SQL developer we cannot see the Product Table but can see other tables.

If I install ODET v2 and use the report account I can see the product table on an windows account that cannot view it in SQL Developer.

It has to be something to do with SQL Developer and windows accounts?

Any ideas.. help appreciated.

Comment: The way I see it, this: "We do not have admin access to Oracle DB, our sales system provider runs it." says it all. Talk to your sales system provider.

Comment: Have you checked the permissions granted to the user within your Oracle DB? IIt sounds like you are using Windows authentication, but there should be a user in Oracle as well that needs to have permissions granted for accessing objects within your database.

Comment: @Littlefoot We are... they say it is a Windows issue. but we have duplicated the users and install.

Comment: @gmiley, that does sound like it could be the issue, ill put that forward to them.  Though we are using the same report user for accessing the objects in the db. Just different windows users to run the SQL Developer.

Comment: Just as @gmiley said; looks like "known" Windows users are granted privileges on certain tables (schemas?), while "other tables" you see may - actually - be public synonyms and are visible to everyone. I'd talk to the provider, they *should* know and point you to the right direction.

Comment: @Littlefoot  Ill go back to them with this info and see what they say.  Thanks

Comment: @Littlefoot Done more testing can view the table with ODET on an account that cannot view it with SQL Developer, so issue is not resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell your sales system provider what you are trying to do and request that they grant select privileges on the tables to the user or at least to a common role.

SQLDeveloper is operating as expected and will only show you what you have privileges to see.